# Minimum of random variables with a discounting term

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following problem. Assume that $X_t$ are all i.i.d. random variable uniformly distributed between 0.5 and 1.5, and that $\phi$ is a little larger than 1.

$$Y_t=  \min(X_t, Y_{t-1} \phi)$$

Which of course can be written as

$$Y_t=  \min(X_t, X_{t-1} \phi, Y_{t-2} \phi^2)$$

and therefore

$$Y_t=  \min (X_t, X_{t-1} \phi, X_{t-2} \phi^2,X_{t-3} \phi^3\ldots)$$

Is there an elegant way to describe the probability distribution? Or at least calculate expected mean and variance?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(Y_n>y) = P(X_n>y, X_{n-1}\phi>y, \ldots, X_1\phi^{n-1}>y)$$

$$P(Y_n>y) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P\left(X_i>\max\left(\frac{y}{\phi^{n-i}},0.5\right)\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{\max\left(\frac{y}{\phi^{n-i}},0.5\right)-0.5}{1.5-0.5}\right) \\ = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1.5-\max\left(\frac{y}{\phi^{n-i}},0.5\right)\right)$$

**Edit**: I would just like to attach the following with this answer which might be helpful for OP (or for me to review some useful thoughts related to this question).

If $X_t \sim U(0,1)$, then,

$$P(Y_n>y) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P\left(X_i>\frac{y}{\phi^{n-i}}\right) =
 \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-yq^i) = (y;q)_n$$

where $q = \frac{1}{\phi}$ and $(y;q)_n$ is q-Pochhammer symbol.

$$\log P(Y_n > y) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\log(1-yq^i)$$

Taking derivative wrt $y$ gives,

$$\frac{f_{Y_n}(y)}{1-F_{Y_n}(y)} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{q^i}{1-yq^i}$$

which is the hazard function $h_{Y_n}(y) = \frac{f_{Y_n}(y)}{1-F_{Y_n}(y)}$.

Comment: Could I get one more step?

Comment: The $q$-Pochhammer symbols involved would rather be $(z;q)_n$ with $$z=2y/3\qquad q=1/\phi$$ Even before that, there is another serious mistake in your post, which is to assume that $$0.5<y/\phi^{n-i}<1.5$$ for every $n$ and $i$ involved (which is impossible as soon as $\phi\ne1$).

Comment: @Did I corrected the mistake. I don't think that a nicer expression can be obtained any further. Correct?

Comment: Shouldn't all this be the limit of the product as i goes to infinity?